# Jquery appending parsedate datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

just wondering what im doing wrong, heads is an existing div and I am pretty sure this method should work to :( ive tried giving a date manualy but it doesnt add anything to the div and it doesnt give an error either. Below is the code:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
                        firstDay: 1,
                            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                        inline: true,
                        onSelect: function(dateText){
                        var datez = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateText);
                        $('#heads').append(datez);
                        generatexml(dateText);

                        }
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thx in advance
Toon

Comment: First issue is that your code example doesn't close the datepicker. You're missing `});`

Comment: Where is generatexml defined? Oh, and append should probably be fed a DOM element (e.g. `append('<p>'+datez+'</p>')`), otherwise use .text() or .html().

Comment: nah it worked like that :) its solved ty and generatexml is a function imported from another file to tidy things up a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot append the object so you will need to convert it to a string:

```
$('#heads').append(datez.toString());
```

Comment: ur right :| ive been looking for a way to convert an object to a string and it all showed a way with .clone() and .html() nd stuff :| pfft i need to stop looking to far :D tyvm